# Drawing squares in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I want to achieve the following with a WPF application (in a certain area/defined area):

- When clicking and holding on the app, you can draw a square
- You can do this as many times, but not overlap any squares
- You can drag squares around the application

What do I need to achieve this, I assume a bunch of onclick/onmove's. Is there an easier way, such as using canvas? Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a canvas if you want the squares to appear where the user clicks and drags.

The mouse down event would define one corner and the mouse up the second. You'd have to constrain the movement of the cursor so that the x and y dimensions of the rectangle were the same.

On each mouse move event you'd have to check if the cursor were over one of the existing squares and prevent the square growing any further.

For the dragging of existing squares modify the mouse down event to check what's under the cursor. If it's the canvas start the square drawing mode, if it's a rectangle (square) then start the dragging mode. Again you'd need to use the mouse move event to check that the square doesn't intersect with any existing squares.

Comment: How would I go about checking the overlaps? Could I store the dimensions in some sort of array and calculate it whilst dragging a new square? If so, that sounds a bit intensive for every mouse movement.. I guess I could always check on mouse up.

Comment: @Prisoner as long as there aren't 1000's of squares it shouldn't be too intensive. You can always change the code later if it starts to be a problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. I'll give it a go and see how things go. Any other ideas from other people are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

There's a code project article describing how to drag elements inside a Canvas: [Dragging Elements in a Canvas](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DraggingElementsInCanvas.aspx)

Speaking of ChrisF's mentioning of using a Canvas, I would suggest you use DragCanvas (found in the article)

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I had however already read it earlier but just wanted to get SOs input into the issue. Also, I'd like to do it without using a pre-written class as a learning exercise!